# VS 2008 designer failure: HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

I am using VS 2008 SP1 with some updates, doing SW development in C++/CLI and Winforms. I have one winforms probject, where the designer shows a failure upon opening:

```
HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

bei EnvDTE.CodeFunction.get_FunctionKind()
bei Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeParser.OnTypePopulateMembers(Object sender, EventArgs e)
bei System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration.get_Members()
bei System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
bei System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
bei System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

I can click on "ignore" then and see my whole winforms, being displayed correctly. But I don't want to ignore always, as it is 1) annoying, and 2) I would also ignore real failures, causing corruption on the form during design time (have had that some times before, loosing hours of development time)...

Another winforms project inside the same solution has no designer problems.

What I have tried so far:

- deleting .ncb and .suo, deleting vcproj.user
- cleaning up temp folders and some VS cache folders. But I don't know what more cache folders do exist, so please name all of them in a possible answer.
- removing all controls from the winform, keeping the background functions
- creating another project in the solution, copying the files to that folder
- deleting the .sln solution file, creating it new
- tried to debug the VS using a 2nd VS, but even when I was able to hit the break button on the 2nd VS in time after hitting enter to open the faulty form, I just saw a bunch of assembler lines. Not helpful at all.

What '*solves*' the problem:

- removing all controls from the winform including all functions
- creating a project in another solution, adding the files and necessary references there (they remain at their original path on the hard disk), not modifying anything. This actually confuses me very much...

Any other ideas, how I can remove that failure? It's in VS obviously, as I can compile and run without errors, and even view the form on another VS as described above.
But I want to keep my original VS solution and not open another one.

Comment: do you use any 3rd party COM controls?

Comment: no, I'm not using any COM controls at all. All references go to my own assemblies or .net assemblies. Also, if I used them, the failure should appear in the other solution as well.

Comment: You are going to have to do the leg-work to diagnose this problem.  Delete as much stuff as possible until you have the minimum code required to repro this exception.  Post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem:

I have 2 related projects, where a bunch of functions is 100% identical. In each project, the functions belong to the main form frmMain because the forms partially contain the same controls.

I don't like copy&paste, but due to the reason above I can't move them to a dll/assembly, so I outsourced these functions to a file `frmMain.cpp.h`, which I included in both projects `frmMain.cpp`:

```
proj_1\frmMain.cpp:
#include "frmMain.cpp.h"

proj_2\frmMain.cpp:
#include "..\\proj_1\\frmMain.cpp.h"
```

Maybe  this is not the nicest way, but it's working really fine. Even in the VS designer it had been working for months. Somehow the designer of form #2 decided now, that it doesn't want to accept it any longer.

My solution now is, that I have a 2 copies of the file. But as I'm using SVN externals to create the 2nd copy, I can still avoid copy&paste, and the designer is happy to show me the form again.